# Nginx proxy http PUT chunked to apache

Tags: apache, proxy, nginx, chunked-encoding

Nginx doesn't support chunked requests so i'm tryping to proxy my PUT request to apache, but it seems nginx blocks and sends 411 error even when proxying. Any way I can get nginx to send those requests to apache untouched, as is?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the relevant sections in your config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this could be an option, although not a nice one: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpChunkinModule